# Сортировка массива PHP по названию картинки

Tags: php

Беру картинки из папки

```
<?php
$filenameArray = array();
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/assets/img/slider/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            array_push($filenameArray, "assets/img/slider/$file");
        }
    }

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
?>
```

На локальном хостинге `сначала` берутся картинки с числовым названием, на рабочем хосте как-то в `разнобой`) 
Как можно отсортировать массив `$filenameArray` чтобы сначала например в массиве были картинки с числовым названием, а потом с буквенным?

`P.S.` если сортировке мешает путь `assets/img/slider/` то из конечно массива его можно выбросить

Comment: вы зачем тут читаете все файлы, а потом на клиенте фильтруете картинки только? сразу здесь оставьте только изображения, странно перекладывать эту работу на клиента

Comment: `$images = preg_grep("/(jpe?g|png|gif)$/", glob("path/to/images/*"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort($filenameArray);` или `sort($filenameArray, SORT_STRING);`